# Command `refreshgrub` ? (in the doc for full disk encryption)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, encryption

I am trying to follow the "Troubleshooting" page for full disk encryption to restore a grub boot overwritten by window but the last and critical step `refreshgrub` in the following community page appears to be missing:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption/Troubleshooting

What is the way to proceed knowing that the installation to rescue is an Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic, dual boot with Windows obviously) ?